# Calibrate accelerometer

Tags: accelerometer

I need to calibrate one axis of the accelerometer.

Currently I have a variable `lastVal` which holds the last stored value of the device rotation around that axis. And when I choose to calibrate the accelerometer, the variable `compensateAccel` is changed to the `lastVal`. Then the rotation value after calibration would be `currentVal - compensateAccel`.

When the device lays flat, the rotation values go from 0 to 90 back to 0 degrees. But when I calibrate it for example at 50 degrees, then those values go from 0 to (90-50=40) back to 0.

So how do I keep the previous value interval after calibration?

Comment: The accelerometer of what?

Comment: @ScottHunter Android device, but why does it matter? Isn't the underlying math the same no matter what?

Comment: The math will be trivial when StackOverflow understands your question. Why, for example, is thr value changing when the device lays flat?